# JavaScript media queries breaking greensock

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, gsap

I am trying to create a Navigation Bar that slides in and out when clicked on using JavaScript and Greensock. For some reason, the on click action is randomly not working when clicked on at different sizes but sometimes it works perfectly fine.

My code is below, you can find a live example of this navigation at: http://www.kramergraphicdesign.com/Maura_Website/

```
    var resize = function(){
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  var lastLiWith = $('#logo').width();

  console.log(openOrShut + " this is the true false var");


   if ($(window).width() >= 0 && $(window).width() <= 639 ) {  


          console.log("mobile");
          $("#logo, #close, .arrow-right").click(function()
          {
            console.log("mobile-click");
            if(openOrShut === false)
            {
              TweenLite.to("#custom-nav",".5",{x:viewportWidth-lastLiWith});
              openOrShut = true;
            }

            else{
              TweenLite.to("#custom-nav",".5",{x:0});
              openOrShut = false;
            }
          });

   }

   else if ($(window).width() >= 640 ) {  

          console.log("tablet");
          $("#logo, #close, .arrow-right").click(function()
          {
            console.log("tablet-click");
            if(openOrShut === false)
            {
              TweenLite.to("#custom-nav",".5",{x:400});
              openOrShut = true;
            }

            else{
              TweenLite.to("#custom-nav",".5",{x:0});
              openOrShut = false;
            }
          });


   } 

   else if ($(window).width() >= 1025 && $(window).width() <= 10000 ) {  

          console.log("dekstop");
          $("#logo, #close, .arrow-right").click(function()
          {
            console.log("desktop-click");
            if(openOrShut === false)
            {
              TweenLite.to("#custom-nav",".5",{x:400});
              openOrShut = true;
            }

            else{
              TweenLite.to("#custom-nav",".5",{x:0});
              openOrShut = false;
            }
          });

   } 
 };





$(document).ready(resize);



$(window).resize(function(){

resize();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `resize` event can occur an awful lot, especially during a drag to resize the window. This means two things:

1. Minimise the amount of work you do so it runs fast, or [*debounce*](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the function (e.g. [using Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce)) so it only runs after you stop receiving resize events for a short time.
2. More importantly, you are adding a new `click` handler *every single time*.

So the reason it "randomly" doesn't do anything is that whenever you click, you actually run your function to toggle the menu many, many times if you have previously resized the window at all. If that number of times happens to be even, then there is no net effect.

There are probably a number of ways to fix this, but here are two:

1. Attach a click handler once, but check the width inside the handler to determine how far to animate it to / how to respond differently to different sizes.
2. Unregister existing click events first (using jQuery's `.off()`) before re-adding them, so there is only ever the one handler registered. I recommend using an event namespace so you can deregister everything on the namespace at once.

Bonus observation: your condition for the tablet widths means the desktop code will never run, because there is no `<= 1024` condition for the tablet block.